# PHP imap_append for pop3

Tags: php, email, pop3

I am trying to move emails between 2 accounts for a bounce handler using PHP but I am getting this warning,
"Append not valid for POP3".

Is there a equivalent of imap_append on POP3 or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. POP3 is a download only protocol. You'll have to use some other mechanism (like SMTP?) to get mail into the mailbox.